# Error: The element has a type attribute as well as an anonymous child type

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

### Nested complex XSD elements with type attribute

Just trying to get my head around why can't a complex element in XSD have a type attribute and a nested complex element in it? . After all type is just a user defined data type and so should be able to contain anything including other user defined data types as well ?.

The XSD parser throws an error :

> The element has a type attribute as well as an anonymous child type

Or have I missed something in my understanding?

So, if I must achieve the below XSD, is it possible?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A" type ="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B" type ="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="C" type ="C">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="SomeElement" type="xs:int"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### An element's type can be named *or* anonymous

**Intuitively**, both together would be impossible because ***named*** and ***anonymous*** are **opposites**.

**Officially**, the exact constraint being violated in the [W3C XML Schema Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) is [**`src-element.3`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#src-element):

> **Schema Representation Constraint: Element Declaration Representation OK**
>
> In addition to the conditions imposed on `<element>` element
>   information items by the schema for schemas: all of the following must
>   be true:
>
> 3. type and either `<simpleType>` or `<complexType>` are mutually exclusive.
>
>    <sub><sup>[*1, 2, and 4 elided; see full constraint [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#src-element)*]</sup></sub>

### XSD using named types

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A" type="A"/>
  <xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="B" type="B">
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="C" type="C">
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="C">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SomeElement" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### XSD using anonymous types

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="C">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="SomeElement" type="xs:int"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, that makes sence and have accepted this answer, just curious what is a business use case where someone would use a named type? , does it impact ? as the final xml wil only tags as such

Comment: Named types are important for type sharing.  There are several related XSD design patterns to consider; see [Schema scope: Primer and best practices](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemascope/)