# The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType with attributes

Tags: xml, types, xsd, attributes

I am very (*very*) new to XSD and XML in general so I have begun by generating my XSD schema using an online tool from my proposed XML document. Part of the XML is:

```
    <code base="16">2A</code>
```

The XSD generated by the tool for this is:

```
    <xs:element name="code" type="xs:int">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="base" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Which seems logical enough to me; there is an element named `code` that has values of type `int`, the element can have an attribute with a name of `base` who's value is also of type `int`.

Yet when I open this in Visual Studio, it complains about `xs:element` tag because:

> The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType

Which unfortunately also seems logical, if the type is defined in the element, why is there further definition of the type with the `complexType` tag?

Thus the crux of my problem; how to properly define an element that has a typed value and also a typed attribute, in XSD?

I have seen this question: [The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200754/the-type-attribute-cannot-be-present-with-either-simpletype-or-complextype) but it was just different enough that I, with my n00b-level knowledge of XSD, did not understand the answer at all.

The suggested duplicate [Error: The element has a type attribute as well as an anonymous child type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34698770/1292918) is about attributes with nested elements... this questing is about an attribute on an element that is not nested but that has type on both attribute and element (if that's the same thing, my level of knowledge is too low to grasp it and so I still need further explanation)

Comment: *Regarding the now deleted comment from OP that duplicate link doesn't answer his question...*  You cannot have both a `type` attribute and an anonymous complex type on a single element, as stated by the duplicate link.  The duplicate link also shows how to correct the problem:  Either use named or anonymous types -- just not both at the same time.   What part do you not understand?

Comment: @kjhughes You do not seem to be taking into account the fact that I am, as stated, very new to XML. I do knot know what you mean by "anonymous type" nor how it refers to what I have asked. The duplicate link shows how to nest a bunch of typed elements to satisfy a contrived example; it does not mention attributes.

Comment: @kjhughes sorry, I moved the comment content into the question

Comment: You cannot use both `xs:element/@type="xs:int"` attribute and a `xs:element/xs:complexType` child element (anonymous type) concurrently; those approaches are mutually exclusive.  The duplicate link shows how to use either `type` attributes or `complexType` child elements, which is precisely what you must do too.

Comment: @kjhughes OK, I see that a `complexType` conflicts with the `type` of the element, but Im sorry, I do not see then how to set the type for both the attribute value *and* the element value. The answer there seems to indicate that I should instead nest another element to hold the value within the element with the attribute... but this is not what is intended, am I incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links you mention address the direct error by which you cannot specify both a `xs:element/@type="xs:int"` attribute and a `xs:element/xs:complexType` child element (anonymous type) concurrently.

What remains to explain is how you actually can achieve your goal to write an XSD that would validate your XML,

```
<code base="16">2A</code>
```

The following XSD will do so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="code">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="base" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually found https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_text.asp at the same time you posted - good to have the confirmation, thanks for sticking with my n00bness!